# Matrix Exponentiation in Olympiad Problem

Tags: matrices, contest-math, exponentiation

I've seen a problem that gives
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
4 & -\sqrt5\\
2\sqrt5 & -3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and asks to find all pairs $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}$, with $|m|\leq n$ such that:

$A^n -(n^2+m)A$

has all integer entries.
I've calculated the char. polynomyal (which is $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2-\lambda-2$) but I have no idea of how can I use it to obtain what the problem asks. Also, probably is it better to calculate for small exponents *n* but I don't see an imediate reason for that.

Comment: Which contest is this from ?

Comment: You can compute a closed form for $A^n$, either from the eigenvalues or by guessing.

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks.